# Restricting access to particular GCP App Engine service with GCP API key?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, api-key

I have multiple app engine services in a single gcp project. I'm wondering if there is a way to restrict access to individual services using a GCP API key?

I've gone through the docs and haven't found anything. The API Credentials Admin interface only appears to allow IP filtering per GCP service (not individual app engine services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is no. You must create a new GCP project.